# Question about this Hand

Tags: rules

I'm starting to learn about Poker. When I was watching this match and I cannot understand about this hand.

Why did `AQ` win the pot? Both them had two pair, and `KKJJ` win over `AA66`. Sure I'm wrong, would like explanation about this hand.

[image]

Comment: Looking more closely, I noted my mistake, "A" Pair win over a "J" Pair or "K"

Comment: there is the `5-card rule` of poker. Yes, they're both 2-pairs, but they kinda read like `AA66Q` vs `KKJJA`. The higher pair of the two wins the battle.

Comment: Pedantic note... The best 5-card hand is AA66K.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer, oops :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Poker the highest card always wins.  The person on the left had two pair Kings and Jacks.  The person on the right had two pair Aces and sixes.

We first determine hand strength.  Both players have two pair.  Since two pair are equal we need to dig a bit deeper.  Player ones highest pair is Kings, player twos highest pair is Aces.  Player two wins.

If player one would have had AJ instead of KJ it would have changed the outcome like this.  Player one has two pair, player two has two pair.  The hand strength is equal so we need to dig a bit deeper.  Player one's highest pair are Aces, players two highest pair are aces.  Highest pair matches, we need to dig deeper.  Player ones second highest pair is jacks.  Players two second highest pair is sixes.  Player one would have won in that scenario.